# Rails fine-uploader icons can't show in browser give error without gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, icons, fine-uploader

[In console screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99qO1.png)  is that, also in /assets/admin included images, and in *fine-uploader-gallery.css* included like
`background: url("edit.gif");` that. How we can fix this images or icons?
I hope, explaining well.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you do `rake assets:precompile`

Comment: Yes i do, but currently stil error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the file .css to .scss and use the syntax of scss:

```
background: image-url("admin/edit.gif") no-repeat 0 0;
```

Comment: Yes I try but, not found again. I try for path all possible path, but same error

Comment: Maybe you can change the file .css to .scss and use the syntax of scss: background: image-url("admin/edit.gif") no-repeat 0 0;

Comment: Yes, now solving this issue. Thank you for your help